# Make multiple arrays into a single array

Tags: ruby

Given

```
arr = [5,6,7]
aa  = [1,2,3,arr,8,9]
```

I wish to produce the array

```
b = [[1,2,3,5,8,9], [1,2,3,6,8,9], [1,2,3,7,8,9]]
```

Notice that all three elements of `b` begin with the elements of `aa` that precede `arr` (the "beginners") and end with the elements of `aa` that follow `arr` (the "enders). The `i`th element of `arr` is then inserted into the `i`th element of `b`, in between the "beginners" and the "enders". The size of `b` therefore equals the size of `arr`.

More generally, the elements of `aa` that precede or follow `arr` can be any objects other than arrays (not necessarily integers).

**Note:** The original statement of this question had

```
aa = [1,2,3,arr,8]
```

and the intent was to produce the array

```
b = [[1,2,3,5,8],[1,2,3,6,8],[1,2,3,7,8]]
```

That is why some of the answers do not reflect the revised example above.

Comment: sonukrishna, I have taken the liberty of clarifying your question to conform with my understanding of what you wish to do. My understanding is shared by everyone who has offered a solution to date. I trust this is what you want to do.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I shared the understanding of you and the others who answered.  I never found this question unclear; I wish the voters would have left a comment saying what was unclear to them.

Answer (score 2):

```
▶ max_sz = aa.map { |e| [*e].size }.max
#⇒ 3
▶ aa.map { |e| e.is_a?(Array) ? e : [e] * max_sz }.transpose
#⇒ [[1,2,3,5,8],[1,2,3,6,8],[1,2,3,7,8]]
```

or, maybe more clear:

```
▶ aa.map { |e| ([*e] * max_sz).take(max_sz) }.transpose
```

Comment: Thank dear  ,its a great help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
nested = aa.select { |ele| ele.is_a? Array }.flatten
aa = aa.select { |ele| !ele.is_a? Array }
result = []
nested.each { |ele| result << ([aa + [ele]].flatten.sort) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like this:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, [5, 6, 7], 8]

# get fixnum
numbers = arr.select { |i| !(Array === i) }

output = arr.each.with_index.with_object(Array.new([])) do |(a, i), exp|
  a.each { |k| exp << numbers.dup.insert(i, k) } if Array === a
end

p output
# => [[1, 2, 3, 5, 8], [1, 2, 3, 6, 8], [1, 2, 3, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: Thanks for this response.

Answer (score 0):

```
first, mid, last = aa.chunk(&:class).map { |_,e| e.flatten }
  #=> [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [8]] 
[first].product(mid.product([last])).map(&:flatten)
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 5, 8], [1, 2, 3, 6, 8], [1, 2, 3, 7, 8]]
```

The steps are as follows

```
enum = aa.chunk(&:class)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007ff64a1699f8>:each>
```

We can see the elements that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array.

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[Fixnum, [1, 2, 3]], [Array, [[5, 6, 7]]], [Fixnum, [8]]]
```

Continuing,

```
first, mid, last = enum.map { |_,e| e.flatten }
  #=> [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [8]] 
first
  #=> [1, 2, 3] 
mid
  #=> [5, 6, 7] 
last
  #=> [8] 

a = mid.product([last])
  #=> [[5, [8]], [6, [8]], [7, [8]]] 
b = [first].product(a)
  #=> [[[1, 2, 3], [5, [8]]],
  #    [[1, 2, 3], [6, [8]]],
  #    [[1, 2, 3], [7, [8]]]] 
b.map(&:flatten)
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
  #    [1, 2, 3, 6, 8],
  #    [1, 2, 3, 7, 8]]
```